# Numbers on an analog clock in processing

Tags: javascript, processing

just need a little help with the numbers on an analog clock in processing 3.3.6
I believe I'm close, but I can't really seem to crack the code.

I need to add numbers on the inside of the clock ticks (0-11) corresponding to an average clock during the AM, and 12-23 during the PM.
Also try and number the minutes as well (every 5 minutes, so 0, 5, 10, up to 55).

It should look like this:

[image: clock]

Here is the code so far:

```
    void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  colorMode(HSB);
  background(0);
  frameRate(1);
  surface.setResizable(true);
}



  void draw()
  {
    float h, m, s;
    float radius;
    float cx, cy;

    float clockface;
    float hoursRadius, minutesRadius, secondsRadius;
    float hoursTick, minutesTick;
    float hoursNum, minutesNum;
    float hoursNumSize, minutesNumSize;


    radius = min(height/2.0, width/2.0);
    cx = width/2.0;
    cy = height/2.0;



    clockface = radius * 0.9;
   hoursRadius = radius * 0.5;
   minutesRadius = radius * 0.65;
   secondsRadius = radius * 0.72;
   hoursTick = radius * 0.05;
   minutesTick = hoursTick * 0.5;




   // get time
   s = second();
   m = minute();
   h = hour()%12 + m/60.0;



   // draw clock face
   fill(40);
   noStroke();
   ellipseMode(RADIUS);
   ellipse(cx, cy, clockface, clockface);



  // draw the hands
  drawHand(cx, cy, s*6.0, secondsRadius, 2);
  drawHand(cx, cy, m*6.0, minutesRadius, 3);
  drawHand(cx, cy, h*30.0, hoursRadius, 5);



  // draw the ticks
  for( int i=0; i<60; i++) {
    if (i%5==0) {
   drawTick(cx, cy, i*6, secondsRadius, hoursTick); 
    }
    else {
      drawTick(cx, cy, i*6, secondsRadius, minutesTick); 
    }
  }
  }



  void drawTick(float x, float y, float angle, float len, float weight) {
    fill(angleToColor(angle));
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(x + cos(radians(angle-90))*len, y + sin(radians(angle-90))*len,
    weight, weight); 
  }
  void drawHand(float x, float y, float angle, float len, float weight) {
    strokeWeight(weight);
    stroke(angleToColor(angle));
  line(x, y, x + cos(radians(angle-90))*len, y + sin(radians(angle-90))*len);
  }



 color angleToColor(float angle) {
    return color(map(angle, 0, 360, 0, 256), 255, 255);
  }



  void drawNum(float x, float y, float angle, float len, float tsize, int num) {
    fill(angleToColor(angle));
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(x + cos(radians(angle-90))*len, y + sin(radians(angle-90))*len,
  tsize, num);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example on how to draw hour numbers, you can make the minutes on the same principle.

In your `draw` method call `drawHourNums`, it takes a boolean, **true** if it is AM, **false** if it is PM, you can deduce that from the current time

```
drawHourNums(false);
```

`drawHourNums` will call the `drawHourNum` method for each number from 0 to 11

```
void drawHourNums(boolean am) {
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {
    drawHourNum(i, am);
  }
}
```

`drawHourNum` will draw a number given its index on the clock and the time of the day. It has pretty much the same algorithm as your `drawTick` and `drawHand` methods, I just adapted it.

`angle` is the angle from the center (360/12)-90 * index
`len` is the distance to the center
`num` will be the same as `index` if AM and `index+12` for PM

```
void drawHourNum(int numIndex, boolean am) {
  PFont f = createFont("Arial",16,true);
  textFont(f,16);
  fill(100);
  float angle = numIndex*(360/12)-90;
  float len = 145;
  float x = width/2.0 + cos(radians(angle))*len;
  float y = height/2.0 + sin(radians(angle))*len;
  int num = am ? numIndex : numIndex + 12;
  text(num, x, y);
}
```